# Multiple @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotations

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

If multiple configuration classes have the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation, then is one used and one ignored?

In a spring boot application there are two instances of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`- one is annotated with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(secured = true)`, and another has `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`.  But so far I cannot get the `@PreAuthorize` annotation to work. With only one annotation I can see verify it is being applied.
eg

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class FirstConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class AnotherConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
...
```

Does spring-security support multiple configuration classes being annotated with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity?
Is there a way to see what has actually been configured?

Answer (score 3):

I debug it (into springframework source) to see what it was being load and in which order.

I had a situation similar where I had a library (which I couldn't change) that configures `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)`.

And I wanted to use `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)`

What was happening it was that the library configurations was being loaded over my configuration (only the last one being loaded would be used)

I tried to use `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE, ...` but with no effect.

My solution was to set the order that I wanted by importing the library configuration at my configuration like this:

```
@Import(LibraryConfig.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class MyConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    /* my code */
}
```

PLUS: I found out that my situation is even more complicated, since the library that I'm using configures `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` more than once.
So the behave was a bit different and to force the use of my configurations I had to override the implementations of this methods:

```
@Bean
public MethodSecurityMetadataSource methodSecurityMetadataSource() {
    return super.methodSecurityMetadataSource();
}

@Bean
public MethodInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor() throws Exception {
    return super.methodSecurityInterceptor();
}

@Bean
public PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice preInvocationAuthorizationAdvice() {
    return super.preInvocationAuthorizationAdvice();
}
```

Comment: Ran into the same issue on one of our products and this helped solve the problem.

Comment: in my case in security config, it has ©EnableGlobalMethodSecurity, & another in a different configuration for MethodSecurityConfig for custom method in ©PreAuthroize. As you said, I removed EnableGlobalMethodSecurity from MethodSecurityExpressionHandler and added ©Import(MethodSecurityConfig.class), but I am still getting the error. Am I doing it right? Instead of keeping it in both, need to remove it from one & add the config in ©Import in the other one?